# Django: Create Submodel in Model

Tags: python, django

Suppose I have two models, Book and Page, such there is a one-to-many relationship between Page to Book. I would like each Book model, to have a function which creates a bunch of Pages for the respective Book model, but I'm not sure how to associate each Page's foreign key back to the Book instance it was created in.

I currently have an associate function, which finds the correct book amongst all the possible books, and I'm sure there's a better way, but I can't seem to find it. Is it possible to set the foreignkey to self?

Comment: Ah, that was stupid of me, I suppose I could just use pk=self.pk

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
class Page(models.Model):
    # default related_name would be `page_set` but `pages`
    # seems a bit more intuitive, your choice.
    book = models.ForeignKey("yourapp.Book", related_name="pages")


class Book(models.Model):
    # ...

    # you can use self as the instance and magically you have
    # this `pages` attr which is a related manager, like `Page.objects`
    # but limited to the particular Book's pages.
    def special_page_create(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.pages.create(
            # ...
        )
        # ...
```

then, you have a book instance, you have a related manager,

```
book = Book.objects.get(...
book.pages.create(...
page, created = book.pages.get_or_create(...
pages_gte_42 = book.pages.filter(num__gte=42)
# etc
```

let me know what else you need to know. The reverse relationship is semi-magical; you don't declare anything on the Book class but you get the related manager on the `Book` instances.

Comment: If you are doing this inside the Book class, would you just `self.pages.create(...)` and would this automatically link the book attribute in Page to `self`?

Answer (score 2):

would try something like this:

```
Class Page(models.Model):
    #Your fields, like a name or whatever
    name = models.CharField(max_length=60)

    Book= models.ForeignKey("Book")


Class Book(models.Model):
    #Your fields again       

    def create_page(self):
        "Adds a page to the book"
        #Do what you need to do
        page = Page(name="TitlePage", Book=self)
        page.save()
```

Or something like that... I think the order of the classes is important too.

Comment: Oh, can you just use self, without any attributes? :O

Comment: I think so. Did this work or help you enough to consider accepting my answer? :)

Answer (score 1):

There is a one-to-many relationship between Book and Page. This means that one Book has several Pages and each Page only one Book.

In a database (and therefore in an ORM mapper) you would model this by creating a foreign key in Page. This foreign key would point to the Book instance that contains these Pages.

If you want to find the Pages for a Book, you'd query the Pages table for all Pages with the same foreign key as the primary key of the Book.

Comment: Yes, I'm asking how to create Page instances in the Book model class, how I would point the Page's foreign key back to the instance of Book I am in

Comment: Maybe have a look at the example code from K-man? Just make sure you correct his capitalisation. "Book" is sometimes uppercased where it should not be.